# Log contains errors - mostly occuring at boot

Tags: 22.04, log

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX425EA
Intel Core i5-11357G
8GB RAM, 2TB NVMe drive

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS

I'm getting some error messages when I boot which I can see in the logs - for example this evening:

```
21:32:40 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
21:32:12 sudo:     will : a password is required ; PWD=/home/will ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime
21:31:55 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
21:31:55 gnome-session-b: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
21:31:54 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
21:31:52 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
21:31:46 systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
21:31:44 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
21:31:43 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
21:31:43 gnome-session-b: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
21:31:43 kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
21:31:42 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
21:31:41 avahi-daemon: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
21:31:41 systemd-udevd: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
21:31:41 kernel: pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
21:31:41 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20210730/dspkginit-438)
```

And earlier today:

```
16:44:25 gdm3: Gdm: Failed to contact accountsservice: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Accounts: Transaction for accounts-daemon.service/start is destructive (systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' is included in transaction).
16:38:16 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
16:37:27 kernel: FAT-fs (sda1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
16:37:27 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 1, lost async page write
16:37:27 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 8193 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
16:37:07 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
15:35:50 kernel: usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
14:03:28 sudo:     will : a password is required ; PWD=/home/will ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime
14:02:53 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
14:02:52 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
14:02:51 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
14:02:28 systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
14:02:25 kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
14:02:24 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
14:02:23 systemd-udevd: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
14:02:23 kernel: pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
14:02:23 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20210730/dspkginit-438)
```

System seems to be working normally - if it's nothing to worry about I am happy to ignore them but wanted to know if there's anything I need to deal with before it gets more serious?

Many thanks.